# String index line vs line without index

Tags: python, string, indexing, letter

I was working on an task for a course that consisted of a program which only prints words which start with a defined range of letters.

I was trying to use this code unsuccessfully:

```
sentence = input("Enter a one sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ")
word = ""

for letter in sentence:
    if letter.isalpha():
        word += letter
    else:
        if word[0].lower() >= "h".lower():
            print(word.upper())
            word = ""                   
        else:
            word = ""

print(word.upper())
```

I was getting an `index out of range` error. I only got it to work when I replaced the line
`(word[0].lower() >= "h".lower())`
with the line
`(word.lower() >= "h".lower())`.

Why the line addressing the string index doesn't work?

Comment: When `word` is empty, `word[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! But then every time I use a line like (word >= "h") it automatically singles out the first letter of the word contained in the variable  "word" and checks if it comes before or after "h"?

Comment: When you compare strings, you compare them character by character until you run out of either of them. So if you compare a string with 10 letters with another string that only has 1 letter, you only have to compare the first characters.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get that error when `word` is an empty string.

This will happen if you have two non-alphabetic characters in a row. After checking the first letter, you assign `word = ""`. Then when you're processing the next character, `word` is still empty, so there's no `word[0]`.

If the first letter is at least "h"`, then so is the whole word, so there's no need to index it. Just write:

```
if word.lower() >= "h":
```

Or you could check whether there's anything in `word` first:

```
if word and word[0].lower() >= "h":
```

There's no need to write `"h".lower()`. It's already lowercase.

Since you need to reinitialize `word` whether it starts with a letter in the range or not, take that assignment out

So the corrected code should be:

```
for letter in sentence:
    if letter.isalpha():
        word += letter
    else:
        if word and word[0].lower() >= "h":
            print(word.upper())
        word = ""
```